# Help with sql and strings

Tags: php, mysql, sql

this is my mysql query:

```
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO Coordenadas (ID, LAT, LNG, DESCRICAO) VALUES ($id, $coords[1], $coords[0], $string_cortada)");
```

when I echo $id, $coords[0], $coords[1] and $string_cortada with this:

```
echo '</br>$id:'.$id.'</br>coordenadas:'.$coords[1].','.$coords[0].'</br>string: ' . $string_cortada;):
```

this is what I get:

```
$id: 1
coordenadas:-22.9028102,-43.2498512
string: marechal rondon 

$id: 2
coordenadas:-22.9824202,-43.3605722
string: rua joana angelica 

$id: 3
coordenadas:-22.8866218,-43.3699090
string: passarela barra
```

working data, but when I do:

```
mysql> select * from coordenadas;
```

this is the output:

```
+----+------+-------------+-------------+-----------+------+
| ID | TIPO | LAT         | LNG         | DESCRICAO | DATA |
+----+------+-------------+-------------+-----------+------+
|  2 | NULL | -22.8544942 | -43.5350719 | 1         | NULL |
+----+------+-------------+-------------+-----------+------+
```

DESCRICAO didn't work, TIPO didn't work, only LAT and LNG, I can't find why !!

this is coordenadas table description:

```
mysql> desc coordenadas;
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| ID        | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| TIPO      | varchar(15)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| LAT       | double       | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| LNG       | double       | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| DESCRICAO | varchar(150) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| DATA      | date         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

thanks

Comment: Notice that he numbers (`double`) work but the strings (`varchar`) don't.

Comment: do you mean TIPO and DATA ? not TIPO and DESCRICAO ?

Answer (score 4):

You have an error in your SQL query:

```
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO Coordenadas (ID, LAT, LNG, DESCRICAO) VALUES ($id, $coords[1], $coords[0], $string_cortada)");
```

$string_cortada needs to be **encapsulated with speech marks as it is a string.** Change it to:

```
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO Coordenadas (ID, LAT, LNG, DESCRICAO) VALUES ($id, $coords[1], $coords[0], '$string_cortada')");
```

*For future debugging* I would write SQL queries in PHP like so:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO Coordenadas (ID, LAT, LNG, DESCRICAO) VALUES ($id, $coords[1],        $coords[0], '$string_cortada')"

$result = mysql_query($query) 

if (!$result) {
 $message  = 'Invalid query: ' . mysql_error() . "\n";
 $message .= 'Whole query: ' . $query;
 die($message);
}
```

This way you can see what the query sent to your database looks like and also see the cause of the error when an error occurs. This should help you **quickly identify any future formatting errors**.

To remove white space surrounding (at the beginning and end) a string you can use the trim() method as so:

```
$text = trim($text);
```

To remove all whitespace from a string you can use preg_replace like so:

```
$text = preg_replace('/ /', '', $text);
```

Comment: Added how to remove whitespace from a string.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify TIPO in your input-Query...
And for DESCRICAO try using singlequotes like

```
VALUES ($id, $coords[1], $coords[0], '$string_cortada')
```